# Make network share accessible to multiple users on OSX

Tags: macos, mount, network-shares, cifs, afp

My goal is to mount a shared folder from a Synology to a Mac running 10.9.1, only I want the mount point to be accessible to all users in group `staff`. The share is made accessible by the synology through AFP and SMB, and I could activate NFS sharing as well. The share holds photos that are accessed by Picasa. Picasa's DB is stored in a local folder that is accessible to the `staff` group. I need to share Picasa's DB because otherwise my users won't be able to share the face recognition DB that goes with it. I'm not storing the DB on the NAS though since it is advised not to.

I tried using the automount method and plain old /etc/fstab syntax, to no avail. I can mount the share all right using both methods, but only the user doing the mount can actually access it. I used the `noowners` switch for afp and the `-d` and `-f` switch for smb/cifs. They seem to work when checking rights with `ls -l`, but other users still get a `permission denied` message when trying to access it. It makes me wonder about the usefulness of said switches, but whatever.

So my question is: is it possible to mount a network share and have it be accessible to more than one user on the computer ? The complexity of doing this on OSX is kind of driving me crazy. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That would be very insecure if there is such system that allows multi-users to access a single-user entry point. Why not do a Sync on the remote folder? Let the single user connect, Sync the content of the remote server to the local drive, and let all other users access the content on the local drive, which will be synced back to the remote server?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm using a dedicated user to mount this share, and all the users with access to the computer are trusted. So no, security is not at all a concern here. As for the sync solution, this would kind of defeat the very reason I bought the NAS system: to free up space on the computer.

Comment: Why not every users simply connect to the NAS drive directly from their own computer, with that "shared" username and password? Or you prefer NOT to give away that username/password to them? Maybe create an OSX shell script to do the mounting that each logged in user can run when they are logging in? Of course any smarter user can look up that shell script and get the username/password out of the script..